# What is Bot in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, lightning

What is the meaning of bots in terms of Salesforce, I am hearing these words like 'Lightning Bots', 'Einstein Bots' etc if someone can explain what is the bot in general and then with one example that would be a great help.

Comment: Bots are automated procedures that interact with people. You can read about Einstein bots on the official salesforce dev page https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/06/summer18-einstein-bots-for-the-people.html

Answer (score 0):

Habib
Sorry for quite a late reply. Salesforce Einstein is an artificial intelligence (AI) technology that has been developed for the Salesforce Customer Success Platform.The main target of Einstein is to give sales and marketing departments more comprehensive and up-to-date views of customers and sales prospects. In the same time a Lightning Component  provides the instant messaging-like interface to communicate with the bot. I've spotted an interesting article on this topic.https://corevalue.net/what-is-salesforce/ Hope it will help